# post in update panel returns 0|error|500| reason or how to handle the error to see better description

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an update panel which contains a few controls, a Place Holder which is dynamically populated (i don't know if this is what is causing the error) and after the post is made the server is returning 0|error|500| only that, everything is working fine in my development machine, but something is wrong on server (Windows Server 2008, IIS 7) any thoughts about what's happening or any approach to catch that error on server and view the details of the error.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the [ScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx) event and do some logging there. You might find that the error details have been logged to the event log on the server anyway. Most ASP.NET errors seem to be.